# Cannot set property of innerHTML to null

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have this function that calls ajax and returns a string of code. that particular string of code i would like to set inside a div. but i keep getting this error (title). I have already made sure that the document is loaded properly. but still no succes.

```
function loadCart(){
    // load in all the products with ajax
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get("loadCart.php", function(data){
            console.log(data);
            document.getElementById("#cartContent").innerHTML = data;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you possibly show us the html tag you are trying to change? Also what is "data" console.loging?

Comment: its an empty div, and data is just a string of html tags

Comment: Right ; but to truly understand your problem we need to see the string html tags that is being print out from data. It seem that where the problem is coming from

Comment: That is definitely not the error you see in the console. You're using a CSS selector with a method that does not understand those types of selectors. Either use jQuery to modify the element or use the correct id selector.